# Fetching data from GCP Bucket gives Timeout error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, supervised-learning

I am trying to train my Keras model on Google Colab TPU. I have split up my train and validation dataset in multiple ".tfrecords" and have put them up in a Google Cloud Platform Bucket and am using that to train.

I was able to flawlessly train my model for up to 34 epochs but now every time I try to continue training I get a similar error -

```
AbortedError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_147599}} All 10 retry attempts failed. The last failure: Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 28 meaning 'Timeout was reached', error details: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 275863891 out of 536870912 bytes received
     when reading gs://{"bucket_name"}/record_0_50.tfrecord
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
```

I have rechecked the availability of the files in my bucket. Are there any quotas/limits that I may have exceeded? Please suggest as to what I may be doing wrong. Thanking you all in anticipation :)

Comment: Have you checked for any prior errors on the logs? such as networking, memory or access issues. Also be sure to be using an up to date version of Tensorflow